# How to removes lines which follows specific pattern in VIM

Tags: vim

I have a file which has below structure:

```
abcd:1
abcd:2
abcd:3
abcd:4
ghi:1
ghi:3
ghi:4
```

All the lines will end with 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. In above example we can see we have `abcd` ending with all (1,2,3,4). but `ghi` doesn't have all values.
I want to remove all those lines for which I have all the values(1,2,3,4) present.
So, after the change, above file should have below content:

```
ghi:1
ghi:3
ghi:4
```

Will it be possible to achieve this somehow?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you considered writing a filter in your favorite scripting language and feeding the file through there? The task seems to be specific to your file layout and not a general editing operation.

Comment: Yes, I can write the script for that purpose. Just wanted to know if this is even achievable or not directly by VIM.

Comment: You can either do it in Vim itself or filter your buffer through an external command (like that script). For reasons mentioned above, I'd prefer the latter.